# Getting primitive values from mobx observable in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a observable store that is being based via props to components that need it.

Console logging from components does show store as expected, but only if I stick to the whole store. Once I start chaining into it I get undefined.

Base store

```
export let TutorStore = observable({
  Tutor: {},
  Queue: [],
  QLength: null
});
```

Component logging

```
checkBtn = () => {
      console.log(this.props.tutorStore);
    };
```

Result [TutorStore in Console as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weNFV.png)

All the correct tutorStore objects are there, with the right data, as expected.
But if I try to chain into a object there are no values attached to it, not behaving as expected.

```
checkBtn = () => {
      console.log(this.props.tutorStore.Tutor);
    };
```

Result [TutorStore.Tutor no values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5riK.png)

I've tried messing around with mobx's toJS method, but it seems unreliable at best.
Considering just assigning the appropriate object to components state, but that defeats the purpose of having a store.

The data is there, so how do I access it?